# Can I add another search engine to Safari?

Tags: search, safari

Any idea, how can I add Wikipedia search to my Safari search box? I'm using Safari 4.0 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using [Glims](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27708/glims) or [Inquisitor](https://web.archive.org/web/20111007174058/http://www.inquisitorx.com/safari/index_en.php), but both require Mac OS. I can't seem to find any way to do this on Windows.

I use Safari on Mac OS myself, but I'd recommend Firefox for your needs. It's also an excellent browser.

Comment: also here's a way (http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20030514035516436) but only for mac :((

Comment: does safari support any hints on the site about search engines? (like the IE8 and <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml">)

Comment: @osgx: No idea, sorry!